# How to represent abstract model dependency in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a something like this in Django:

```
class PublicObject(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    title = models.CharField()
    menu_link = models.ForeignKey('MenuLink')

class MenuLink(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    parents = models.ManyToManyField('self')

class Page(PublicObject):
    page fields...

class BlogEntry(PublicObject)
    blog entry fields...
```

What I want is when I delete a page or a blog entry the coresponding menu link to be deleted also.
How can I do this in Django without breaking the DRY principle?
I must mention:
- Overiding model_delete of the ModelAdmin doesn't work because this function doesn't get called in bulk deletes from Django's actions menu.
- Using the pre_delete model signal doesn't work because it requires the name of a model but doesn't work for an abstract model name. It works only with sender=Page or sender=BlogEntry not with sender=PublicObject. Will I get a big performance penalty if I register this signal for all models and simply check what model my sender is?

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions I can suggest.

1. Why shouldn't you just override `PublicObject.delete`?
2. You may consider another relations model:

   ```
   class PublicObject(models.Model):
       class Meta:
           abstract = True
       title = models.CharField()

   class MenuLink(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField()
       parents = models.ManyToManyField('self')
       public_obj = models.ForeignKey('PublicObject')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your first suggestion works :). The second doesn't. You cannot have a foreignkey to a non existent table.

Comment: Sorry, spoken to soon. First idea is no good either. The delete method doesn't get called for bulk deletes from the admin

Comment: I agree in this case 2nd approach is not a way to go.

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to think about bulk deleting in admin as it's not the model defining issue at all :) You may redefine ``delete_selected`` method in your ModelAdmin subclass, as recommended in docs - in "Warning" box: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#admin-actions)

Comment: Here's a snippet for replacing delete action in admin I've used recently in my project: https://gist.github.com/4190318